# Fill in NaN only in those rows that contain in two Columns NaN

Tags: python, pandas, nan, fill

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fp3a.png)I would like just to fill  the rows (index 3) that in both columns contain NaN (with the 1st of January-1 01  ) Leaving the other rows with NaNs.

problem:

```
index---day----month----year

0-------Nan----03--------93

1-------18-----Nan-------85

2-------8------7---------71

3-------Nan------Nan------75
```

solution

```
index---day----month----year

0-------Nan----03--------93

1-------18-----Nan-------85

2-------8------7---------71

3-------1------01--------75
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried? Also, you just want to fill  one row or the line containing two `NaN`?

Comment: I wan to fill the NaN not just one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with 3 steps. First, you replace all NaN values in only one column by the letter "-" (or an other letter that is not used in your dataset). Secondly, you fill NaN values in columns "day" and "month" with "1" and "01". Finally, you recreate NaN values for "-" values. The code looks like that :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "day" : [np.nan, "18", "08", np.nan, np.nan],
    "month" : ["03", np.nan, "7", np.nan, np.nan],
    "year" : ["93", "85", "71", "75", "56"],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
values = {'day': "1", 'month': "01"}
df = df.fillna("-", limit=1).fillna(value=values).replace("-", np.nan)
df
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! in the function fillna (limit=1) why is needed?

Comment: I use it to select only lines in which you have only one missing value

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change just a specific row by index

```
df.loc[3,["day","month"]]  = [1,1]
```

Comment: Thanks! But this is just for one row. Imagine that you have 500 rows from which 30 have in both columns day and month NaNs. Is this possible to apply for that case?